# Dumper result how check array size

Tags: perl

in my script I have result for example when I print

```
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
print Dumper \%slownik2;
```

I have for example result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '22' => [
                    '29.9',
                    '29.7',
                    '29.5',
                    '29.3',
                    '29.0',
                    '28.1'
                  ],
          '58' => [
                    '29.3'
                  ],
          '66' => [
                    '29.8',
                    '29.8'
                  ],
          '72' => [
                    '28.7'
                  ],
          '91' => [
                    '27.8'
                  ],
          '92' => [
                    '29.9'
                  ],
          '96' => [
                    '28.6'
                  ]
        };
```

And I think this is ok. Now I have a question how now check array size this dumper result in a loop for individual hash. I would like to do that if array size of individual hash dumper is == 1 then form example print something else array size for individual hash result is >1 then do nothing. Than you for your help

Comment: `@$ref` in scalar context checks the number of elements in an array.

Comment: hmm I dont now how please for example

Comment: `my $size = @$ref`

Comment: Can't. It's unclear what you want. You ask "how now check array size this dumper result", but the dumper result is a string, not an array. Even if you meant the dumper *input*, we're talking about a hash not an array.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that:

1. you have a hash as an input of your Dumper
2. each value of your hash is an array
3. what you want to do is to print the key or value of each record only when the array contained in your value(s) has only one record.
4. List item

If that's the case I would suggest writing your own print-routine by:

1. iterating your hash (using `foreach`)
2. getting the length of each array contained in the corresponding value
3. printing this record using `print`

p.s. It would help if you provide an example of the output you expect.